# Which is better while loading Image from Url?

Tags: android, url, bitmap, base64

I am working on `Base64` as well as `Bitmap` image format. can you suggest me which is better to use while loading from the Url ?

Comment: The answer is `Base64`.

Comment: why base64 is better?

Comment: We cannot answer as you did not tell what you try to download. Maybe your image is a .jpg file. So explain better what you are doing first.

Comment: You cannot ask if it is better to use base64. As you can only decode base64 if the server encodes it in base64. You are not giving that info either.

Comment: @ greenapps,what I asked,which is better? not implementation.

Answer (score 0):

It is not too bad converting between the bitmap and base64 format and depending on what you’re trying to do, this can prove quite useful.  If you absolutely don’t want to store the image data on a filesystem, you can just store the base64 string in a database instead.

Base64 is an algorithm mapping all 256 byte values to 64 printable byte values (printable means that those bytes are printed in US-ASCII encoding). This is done by packing 3 input bytes to 4 output bytes. Base64 is generally used in text-based data exchange protocols when there is still a need to transfer some binary data. The best known example is encoding of e-mail attachments.

In android, Normally we send and receive data in the form of string.So if we have image in the Bitmap form then we can not send it to server.A simple function that you need pass bitmap and it will return a string

```
 /**
   * @param bitmap
   * @return converting bitmap and return a string
   */
   public String BitMapToString(Bitmap bitmap){
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos=new  ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG,100, baos);
        byte [] b=baos.toByteArray();
        String temp=Base64.encodeToString(b, Base64.DEFAULT);
        return temp;
  }
```

Here is the reverse procedure for converting string to bitmap but string should Base64 encoding

```
 /**
   * @param encodedString
   * @return bitmap (from given string)
   */
  public Bitmap StringToBitMap(String encodedString){
 try{
   byte [] encodeByte=Base64.decode(encodedString,Base64.DEFAULT);
   Bitmap bitmap=BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(encodeByte, 0, encodeByte.length);
   return bitmap;
 }catch(Exception e){
   e.getMessage();
   return null;
 }
  }
```

Comment: why would someone store it as base64 in the database when storing as ordinary blob can be done?

Comment: Most probably you could use BLOB in you database, convert the image to byte array and store in database.

Comment: so why to use base64 when you can store binary byte data?

Comment: My question is which is better as point to size and memory regarding.

Comment: @Vasant of course binary data is smaller than base64 (base64 encoding makes size roughly 33% larger than their original binary representation)

Comment: You canot say as such. Binary bitmap data of a .jpg file will be more bytes than a base64 encoded .jpg file. I wonder why nobody first askes what kind of data is behind that url.